# THREE.js - Moving objects to rest on an object face

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a curved map of the US that I'm attempting to drop pins on. Right now, I'm just doing some math to find out how far they are from the highest part of the curve and map their height accordingly. Since this map has some states higher or lower than others, this doesn't quite work out. Some pins are floating in space, others are buried in the ground.

What I'd like to be able to do is start them all at a certain height and move them down until they collide with the map face, but I can't find any reliable documentation or SO answers about how to do collision detection in THREE.js.

Is there a better strategy? How can I get these pins to rest their points on this curved map?

[image: The Map in Question]

Comment: If you know where they're supposed to be on the curve, you could use a [`Raycaster`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Raycaster) to find the intersection point on the surface of the map. Create a `Vector3` which represents the position on the curve, well above the map. Then use a `Raycaster` to shoot a ray toward the center point of the curve (not the center of the arc) using `intersectObjects`. The result will include the point at which the raycaster intersected the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed @TheJim01's advice and used a `Raycaster` at each marker's location, pointed it downwards and used the `distance` property of the first intersection to adjust the marker's Y position.

A few gotchas that I got a bit hung up on: It took me a while to realize I needed to use the marker's world position rather than it's local position since they are all children of the map object. Also, I had moved the map's position and rotation before creating the `Raycaster` so "downward" was no longer down. So I just set the markers before moving the map around.

```js
const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();

markers.forEach(marker => {
    raycaster.set(marker.getWorldPosition(), new THREE.Vector3(0, -1, 0).normalize());
    let intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects([map]);
    if(intersects.length) {
        marker.position.y -= intersects[0].distance;
    }
});
```